# Changing API version of visual force page throws error

Tags: visualforce

We have created a visual force page with standard controller and extensions and an action method which gets executed on page load

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Approval_History__c" extensions="Approval_History" action="{!Refresh_Approval_History}">
</apex:page>
```

The current API version is 32.0. I am trying to change API version for VF Page to 42.0. When i try to do that it throws error. Version of apex class used in extensions is already at 42.0.
Error Message is as follows:
 Unknown method 'Approval_History__cStandardController.Refresh_Approval_History()'

Do i need to write new custom controller instead of calling action method from extensions apex class

VisualForce Page is as follows:

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Approval_History__c" extensions="Approval_History" action="{!Refresh_Approval_History}">
</apex:page>
```

Refresh_Approval_History is a function inside extensions class Approval_History

Comment: That error suggests that `Refresh_Approval_History()` is either not the correct name for your method, or your method is expecting some parameters. It's hard to narrow it down more than that without seeing both your Visualforce and your Extension.

Comment: VisualForce Page is as follows: <apex:page standardcontroller="Approval_History__c" extensions="Approval_History" action="{!Refresh_Approval_History}">
</apex:page> and inside Approval_History class there is one method   public pagereference Refresh_Approval_History( List<sObject> ah ) {}

Comment: Things like code, visualforce, and error messages do very poorly in comments. You should instead [edit] your question to include that additional information.

Comment: i have edited question to include VF Page details

Comment: Hi Abhijit, can you change your apex to version42 and click "compile all classes". Then remove the extension and action attribute from VF. Save it and then change it to version 42. Once VF is saved as version 42, edit VF and add extension and action attribute.

Comment: Hi Pranay, I followed steps mentioned by you. I am getting same error after adding extension and action attribute and hitting save to save the VF page

Comment: is calling function in action attribute which is from extension class supported in version 42?